# ArgumentError in Users#pagename - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a new page under my users folder (`mypage.html.erb`), as the content on it needs User data. I'm creating a form/dropdown menu, and for some reason upon putting the following code in, I'm thrown this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x000000021aee18>:0x007fc52025c8e8>

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`  `<%= user.firstname %>` `<%= user.lastname %>`
```

I'm not sure why, as I know `@user` is defined. I've created a number of forms and pulled other User data on other custom pages.

See code:

**mypage.html.erb**

```
<div id="widepage">
  <div class="blue-text-header">Title</div>
  <div class="grey-text-subheader">Subtitle</div>
  <div class="infoheaders">Information</div>

  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :questions, User::QUESTIONS, :to_s, :to_s, 
        :include_blank => true
    %>
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="fullcard">
  <div class="name">
    <%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
    where("firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end

  QUESTIONS = ['hot', 'medium', 'cold']

  has_secure_password

  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes["password"] }

  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
    :styles => {
      :thumb    => ['150x150#',  :jpg, :quality => 100],
      :preview  => ['175x175#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
      :large    => ['600>',      :jpg, :quality => 70],
      :retina   => ['1200>',     :jpg, :quality => 30]
    },
    :convert_options => {
      :thumb    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :preview  => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :large    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :retina   => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5'
    }

  validates_attachment :avatar,
    :presence => true,
    :size => { :in => 0..10.megabytes },
    :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/ }
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color] = "valid"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color] = "invalid"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def mypage
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @user = User.all
    if params[:search]
      @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to @user  
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :aptno, :streetaddress, :city, :country, :stateprov, :poszip, :receive_newsletters, :terms_accepted,  :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :bio)
  end

  # def user_params
  #   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description, :avatar)
  # end

  def new
  end 
end
```

Comment: hope your action is "mypage" in users_controller

Comment: if you change the name of your mypage.html.erb file to show.html.erb or index.html.erb, are you still getting an error?

Comment: I see that `#new` is under `private` -- know that the private keyword, unless inline with a method definition, marks all following methods/etc as PRIVATE. That means `new` is private, when it should not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@user` is an instance variable (ivar). While `user` without the `@` sign is a local variable.

This can be quite confusing when learning Rails as Rails transfers any instance variables defined in the controller to what is called the `view_context`. This `view_context` is a object where rails stuffs all your instance variables and helper methods. The view_context is `self` in your views.

So when you do:

```
def mypage
  @user = User.new
end
```

Rails will provide the instance var `@user` to your view.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
  <%= @user.firstname %><%= @user.lastname %>
<% end %>
```

Another cool trick you can use if you are creating a form or partial where you don't know what the (ivar) is named is to use `.object` on the form builder instance:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%# ... %>
  <%= f.object.firstname %><%= f.object.lastname %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to intialize @user variable in your action and controller

```
@user = User.new(params)
```

Comment: Adding this gives me the following error when I try and pull @user attributes into mypage.html.erb: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in UsersController#mypage

Comment: The issue nows lies in this <%= user.firstname %> <%= user.lastname %>.

You have not initialize 'user' variable , you have only '@user' . And that user doesn't have any attributes set (you called user.firstname and lastname)

Answer (score 0):

If your mypage action is in users controller, initialize the user object first.

```js
def mypage
  @user = User.new()
end
```

You should initialize an object before sending it into a form.

```
@user = User.new()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in the controller

```
def mypage
  @user = User.new
end
```

Comment: Added this to my controller, and I still receive this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x00000001759a08>:0x007f7a92a89c88>):

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<%= @user.firstname %> <%= @user.lastname %>`